# Understand using (+) function with 'IS NULL' expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I know purpose of (+) function and how to use it an expression such as `'where a(+)=b'`. I don't understand using (+) function with 'IS NULL' expression

> where table.valid_end_date(+) IS NULL

Comment: Why do you insist on re-posting the same question 2 hours after it has been closed (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176109/pl-sql-outer-operator-with-null )?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: It certainly looks like 5 people scanned the question long enough to see `(+)` and then voted to close it as a duplicate.  I assume you didn't read this question either?

Comment: @Andomar Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say. The first question was closed as duplicate before I even saw it, and I voted to close for this one as duplicate. Is that what you're asking? Or are you saying that the people closing the original question didn't read it carefully enough?

Comment: My question wasn't duplicate, I know what (+) is, but with 'is null' expression. Because of that I re-ask my question modified.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: I'm suggesting that before you close something as duplicate, you make sure that the original answers the question.

Comment: @ProCeng ProCeng I agree your original question shouldn't have been closed as duplicate. But instead of asking essentially the same question again, you should have edited the original question. It would then have been a candidate for re-opening. Re-asking the same question (even if the second version is much better + clearer) just clutters the site and should be avoided IMHO.

Comment: @Andomar Sorry, I disagree. The OP should have edited their original question instead of re-asking it. If everyone kept repeating their questions just because they had been closed / unanswered, SO would quickly become absolutely useless (nevertheless, I've revoked my close vote for this one).

Comment: @ProCeng, for posterity's sake, could you replace the word, "function", with the word, "operator", so that this could aid people in finding this post?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: Even if your post is one of the very few to be reopened, your question will be old and few people will even see it.  From a practical viewpoint, edit in hopes for reopen is a dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(+) is an "[Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A85397_01/operator.htm#998290)" that "Indicates that the preceding column is the outer join column in a join."

It isn't a function, it takes no arguments, does not (by itself) return any value, you cannot use it in the select clause for calculations. It is just an item of Oracle specific syntax that denotes an outer join.

So, when forming an outer join you have to apply this (+) operator to all parts of that join (otherwise it is no longer an outer join)

and, so `where table.valid_end_date(+) IS NULL` simply means `table` has been outer joined (and it is required that the field valid_end_date IS NULL)

Answer (score 1):

`(+)` is an old, Oracle specific way to write a `left join`.  So when you write `col1(+) is null`, you are adding a condition to the `left join`.  The condition says to match only rows where `col1` is `null`.

Here's an example query:

```
select  *
from    customers c
,       orders o
where   o.customer_id(+) = c.id
        and o.dt(+) is null
```

As you can see at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55602/2/0), for each customer, this returns:

- All existing orders with a `null` date
- If the customer does not have any order with a `null` date, a single generated row with all `null` columns

The equivalent new-syntax query is:

```
select  *
from    customers c
left join
        orders o
on      o.customer_id = c.id
        and o.dt is null
```

I personally think the later syntax is a lot clearer.